# Multiple params for two different object in one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am pretty new in RoR and I am trying to learn a better way to achieve what I want. 
Currently, I have to input boxes to search Book and User in one page. After I enter the book id, it will search through the database and display some detail info about the book in this page. 
If the book returned has a owner(user), the input box for user will be filled automatically and the info about the user will be display in the same page. If the book has no owner, I need to type in the user id in the other input box and the info about the user will be displayed.

The way I am doing it now is that the input of book id and user id will be assigned to params[:book_id] and params[user_id]. And the info of book and user will be displayed if the value of @book and @user exist. 
Here is the code in view:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <p>BookID</p>
        <input type='text' value='<%= params[:book_id]%>' name = 'book_id' placeholder='Enter Book ID here'/>
    </div>
</form>
<form>
    <div>
        <p>User ID</p>
        <input type='text' value='<%= params[:user_id]%>' name = 'user_id' placeholder='Enter User ID here'/>
    </div>
</form>

<% if @book %>
    <%= render 'book'%>
<% end %>

<% if @user%>
    <%= render :partial => 'users/user'%>
<% end %>
```

Here is the code in Controller:

```
def checking 
  @book = Book.find_by(book_id: params["book_id"])
  @user = User.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id])
  if @book && @book.user
    @user = @book.user
  end
end
```

Thanks for helping!

Edit: Thanks Steve's answer. But currently the problem I have is that I can't figure out a way to keep both params at the same time. After I enter the book id and hit enter, the book info will be displayed perfectly. However, when I enter the user id next and hit enter, only the user id is kept in the params and the param[:book_id] is not there. What I want to achieve is something like: /checking?book_id=1234&user_id=5678

Comment: What is the relation between `book` and `user`?

Comment: book belongs to user and user has many books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I Understood you correctly:

you should use one form  for both objects `book_id` and `user_id`

view.html.slim

```
= form_tag checking_path do
  = text_field_tag :book_id
  = text_field_tag :user_id
  = submit_tag :search

- if @book
  = render 'book_partial_path'
- if @user
  = render 'user_partial_path'
```

model Book:

```
scope :search_book, (book_id)-> { find_by(book_id: book_id) if book_id }
```

model User:

```
scope :search_user, (user_id)-> { find_by(user_id: user_id) if user_id }
```

controller:

```
def checking 
  @book = search_book(params[:book_id])
  @user = @book.try(:user) || search_user(params[:user_id]))
end
```

Comment: Your solution solve my problem! Thank you very much. By the way, is there any benefit using scope instead of using the built-in find_by method?

Comment: benefit of scopes is that you can use it in chain (`Model.scope_one(params1).scope_two(params2)`), and without scopes you can get Error. But in your case you can use `find_by`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this...

```
def checking 
  @book = Book.find_by(book_id: params["book_id"])
  @user = User.find_by(user_id: (@book.try(:user_id) || params[:user_id]))
end
```

That will use the `@book.user_id` for the find_by unless it doesn't exist or unless no @book object exits, in which case it'll use the `params` value.

The `try` method will attempt to call `user_id` on `@book` but if `@book` is just `nil` the result of the `try` will return nil.

Comment: I can't. Because in the beginning @ book is nil and evaluating @ book.user_id will result in an no method for nil class error.

Comment: Yes but in the second line of my solution we assign @book

Comment: But when we first start, the params["book_id"] is nil which means Book.find_by(book_id: params["book_id"]) will return nil.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry, didn't realise you call checking even on first display.  My answer now modified to handle that condition.#

Comment: oh thanks. I didn't know that there is a try method, thank for teaching me that:)